# Simplest way to convert all html links in a string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, hyperlink, preg-replace

I am trying to convert a block of text that contains html text - i'd like to find all http links and convert them for link tracking purposes.

So eg anything like this in a string would be converted to the latter

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Some Link</a>

<a href="http://www.mysite.com/tracking.php?url=www.google.com">Some Link</a>
```

Can anyone how to do this taking into account the original string will consists of all sorts of html, images etc..

Comment: Sorry i misunderstand question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this regex :** (UPDATED)

```
<?php

$str = '<h1>Page Title</h1><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>';
$text = preg_replace("/href=\"http\:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/*)?)/","href=\"http://www.mysite.com/tracking.php?url=$1\"",$str);

echo $text;

?>
```

**Outputs :**

```
<h1>Page Title</h1><a href="http://www.mysite.com/tracking.php?url=www.google.com/"">Google</a>
```

Comment: I get the following error:

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in...

Comment: My code below.. (cant seem to get the formatting correct??)

     $str = '<h1>Page Title</h1><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';
     $text = preg_replace('href=\"http\://([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?)\"', 'href=\"YOUR_TRACKING_URL=$1\"', $str);
     echo $text;

Comment: just a quick one..
How would I amend the preg_replace to only replace href's that do not have the 'clients' in the href? (but keeping the existing rule as well)

Comment: @Gaz Could you give me an example of a URL containing 'clients'? (I mean you're obviously not interested in excluding clients.com, but something along the lines of `http://www.yourdomain.com/clients/some_page.php`, right? that's what I want so as to make it more specific) :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<h1>Page Title</h1><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';
$text = preg_replace('href=\"http\://([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?)\"', 'href=\"YOUR_TRACKING_URL=$1\"', $str);
echo $text;
```

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /home/....
(sorry for the duplication)